# Collecting http-equiv with simple html dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am using Simple html DOM to parse different elements from submitted html documents.  I have been trying to figure out how to check for the following

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="100">
```

I have tried to use.

```
foreach($html->find('meta') as $element){
    if($element->http-equiv=='refresh'){ refreshFound(); }
}
```

I receive the error Use of undefined constant equiv. Is there a special way I have to form the statement due to the - symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `$element->attr`

```
foreach ( $html->find('meta') as $element ) {
    var_dump($element->attr);
}
```

Output

```
array
  'http-equiv' => string 'refresh' (length=7)
  'content' => string '100' (length=3)
array
  'http-equiv' => string 'Content-Type' (length=12)
  'content' => string 'text/html; charset=utf-8' (length=24)
array
  'name' => string 'robots' (length=6)
  'content' => string 'noindex' (length=7)
```

Simple Check

```
foreach ( $html->find('meta') as $element ) {
    foreach ( $element->attr as $key => $value ) {
        if ($key == "http-equiv" && $value == 'refresh') {
            echo "FOUND";
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
FOUND
```

Note*

if you use `$element->attr["http-equiv"]` Directly it would generate the error below because sites sometimes don't have `http-equiv`

> Notice: Undefined index: http-equiv

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a subtraction: `$element->http minus equiv`

Why don't you directly find the meta elements with http-equiv attribut containing "refresh"?

From the example page this should work: `$html->find('div[id=hello]', 0)->innertext = 'foo';`

Makes me think that `$html->find('meta[http-equiv=refresh]');` should find the element which has http-equiv with "refresh" content as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
if(@$element->attr['http-equiv'] == 'refresh') { 
    refreshFound(); 
}
```

where `@` silences `Notice: undefined index` warnings, in the case that the document *doesn't* contain a `meta:http-equiv`.